# Sorting a VARCHAR column as FLOAT using the CAST operator don't work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, casting

I can't find a way to sort a varchar column casted as float. Here is my SQL request:

```
SELECT guid, number FROM table ORDER BY 'CAST(number AS FLOAT) DESC'
```

The "number" column is defined like this:

```
number  varchar(20) ascii_general_ci
```

And the values defined in this column for my test are :

```
0.00
200.00
20.00
100.00
```

MySQL totally ignore the CAST operator and sort the columns by guid...

Is there a bug in MySQL or did I do something wrong ?

Comment: ^^ `ORDER BY 'CAST(number AS FLOAT) DESC'` results in the same as `ORDER BY 'foo'` or `ORDER BY 'ehrlkherklth ektl k'`. The `ORDER BY` in your statement does not make sense......

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this trick (helps to sort strings as numbers)-

```
SELECT guid, number FROM table ORDER BY number * 1 DESC
```

It will help MySQL to cast string to number.

---

Another solution -

```
...CAST(value as DECIMAL(10,5))
```

Comment: It work !!! Still don't understand why the CAST operator don't work but your trick solve my problem.

Comment: You cannot cast to FLOAT. Have a look at CAST function reference, there is no FLOAT type.

Comment: Woooh, you're so right, if I do: SELECT guid, number FROM table ORDER BY CAST(number AS SIGNED) DESC without the quotes, it work ! I had try SIGNED but not without the quotes. Thanks a lot

Comment: Note that SIGNED will return integer value.

Answer (score -1):

If you have taken GUID then the size should be `varchar(40)`
Insted of that you can use `uuid()`

I have done it using

```
select uuid(), number order by 'cast(number as float) desc';
```

It's working fine.  If this is not you want can you send your entire code?

Comment: you are just ordering by a fixed string